# How could I prevent brute force retrying password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I send a private link to user via email,

```
  = link_to user_profile_url(user_token: @user.token, user_id: @user.uid), method: :post
```

To avoid let user login again from mobile mail app. I devide to let user login in, if the request has `user_token, user_id` params.

Because my current method can be brute forcely tried in a short time.

What's the best practice to avoid brute force attacks, thanks

```
  def get_user_by_token(user_id=nil ,token=nil)
    if user_id and token
        User.where({id: user_id, token: token}).first
    else 
        nil
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially two complementary options:

1. make the token complex enough to require a reasonably big computation effort. You can use [`SecureRandom.hex`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-hex) or even [`SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-urlsafe_base64) that includes not only letters and digits but also other chars.
2. Throttle the action. Keep track of the HTTP requests to that specific action and block the user by IP if the number of requests per minute is higher than, for example 5.